# Get Value from selectRadio

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've been at this for the whole night.  Can someone help explain how I can get a value back from a SelectRadio?

What I want to do:  When they make a selection from the Radio Button, call a method.  This method then checks what is selected, and assigns my To-Be-Inserted record variable some field values.

That's what I gathered from Google in regards of what I need to do to get this working.

Basically, I have got, as an example:

**VF**

```
 <apex:selectRadio >
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!recOptions}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!pmRecPR}" />             
 </apex:selectRadio>
```

**APEX**

```
    public List<SelectOption> getRecOptions()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

  options.add(new SelectOption('PR', 'PR'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('A', 'A'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('NO', 'NO'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('R', 'R'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('D', 'D'));
   return options;

public void pmRecPR(){


    if (recOptions.getValue() == 'PR'){  // clearly this line doesn't work.  "variable does not exist, recOptions".
         recommendationRecord.PM_Recommendation__c='some_value';
}
```

when I try to declare "recOptions',

```
public list<selectOption> RecOptions() {get;set;}
```

it gives me an error:

> variable does not exist:get.

But didn't I just MAKE a get for it?

Any help is really appreciated.  I'm clearly a beginner and I need to get this done, and It's 2:18am.  Any help, or point in the right direction would be great.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: its not public list<selectOption> RecOptions() {get;set;}, it should be public list<selectOption> RecOptions{get;set;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a public variable in your controller for the selected valu.

**VF:**

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedValue}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!recOptions}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!pmRecPR}" />             
 </apex:selectRadio>
```

**Controller:**

```
    public String selectedValue {get; set;}

    public void pmRecPR(){
        if (selectedValue == 'PR'){ 
               //....blablabla
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'm now getting a value for selectedValue!  Thank you!               On to the next issue... lol... My method doesn't seem to run whether I use event="onchange" or event="onselect".  Ideas?

Comment: GOT IT!  I just had to move the <Apex:ActionSupport> before the <Apex:SelectActions>, but still inside <Apex:selectRadio>.  Thanks again, and hopefully this helps someone down the road!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the action support within the selectoptions tag and change the event to onselect instead of onchange. You also have to specify a public variable in class to hold the selected value.

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedOptionValue}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!recOptions}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onselect" action="{!pmRecPR}" />
      </apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectRadio>

public String selectedOptionValue {get; set;}

 public List<SelectOption> getRecOptions()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

  options.add(new SelectOption('PR', 'PR'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('A', 'A'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('NO', 'NO'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('R', 'R'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('D', 'D'));
   return options;

public void pmRecPR(){

    if(selectedOptionValue == 'SOMEFAKEVALUE'){
        ....
    }

    /*if (recOptions.getValue() == 'PR'){  // clearly this line doesn't work.  "variable does not exist, recOptions".
         recommendationRecord.PM_Recommendation__c='some_value';*/
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: This helped - thank you very much for responding!!